# java code optimization when iterate list

Tags: java, optimization, iteration

It is common to iterate list of elements. Check some conditions and remove some elements from list.

```
for (ChildClass childItem : parent.getChildList()) {
    if (childItem.isRemoveCandidat()) {
    parent.getChildList().remove(childItem);    
    }
}
```

But in this case java.util.ConcurrentModificationException is thrown.

What is the best program pattern in this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). If your list supports [`Iterator.remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) you can use it instead! *It won't throw the exception.*

```
Iteartor<ChildClass> it = parent.getChildList().iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
    if (it.next().isRemoveCandidat()) 
        it.remove();
```

Note: The `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown when you have "started" iterating over a collection and modifies the list during the iteration time (eg in your case it doesn't have anything todo with concurrency. You are using the `List.remove` operation during the iteration and that is the same in this case..).

---

### Full example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);

    for (Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
        if (it.next().equals(2))
            it.remove();

    System.out.println(list); // prints "[1, 3]"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

another option is:

```
for(int i = parent.getChildList().length - 1; i > -1; i--) {

    if(parent.getChildList().get(i).isRemoveCandidat()) {
        parent.getChildList().remove(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ListItrerator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html)

```
for(ListIterator it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext();){
    SomeObject obj = it.next();
    if(obj.somecond()){
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

You can also use [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). But the flexibility of `ListItrerator` over `Iterator` is you can traverse the list both way.